# A possible error related to the evaluation of a double integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

According to the Mathematica, the integral below

```
    NIntegrate[ Log[Log[1/(x y )]]  Log[1/(x y )]^(-0.5 - 1), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,1}]
```

might possibly evaluate to "Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity" for $t=-0.5 - 1$, although my calculations show that  there should be no problem for all the cases with $t>-2$. More exactly, Mathematica yields this result:

**NIntegrate::inumri: "The integrand Log[Log[1/(x y)]]/Log[1/(x y)]^1.5 has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,3.97545*10^-31},{0,1}}"**

So, is it a problem with my code or it's just another problem related to the Mathematica?

Comment: I can see all  kinds of infinities and undefined expressions for x,y -> 0 or 1. Are you really sure about your calculations?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries yeah, pretty sure.

Comment: You divide `1/(xy)` and your domain contains the point `(0,0)`. Your function is undefined there - so the integral may not converge, which is what Mma points out. Your calculations show that it does converge; this doesn't contradict Mma. Apparently it just isn't able to evaluate it. Sometimes rewriting your integrand in a different way helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you perform the change of variables $x = u, y=v/u$, whose Jacobian is $1/u$, the square $0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1$ is transformed to the triangle $0 \le u \le 1, 0 \le v \le u$.  This triangle is the same as $0 \le v \le 1, v \le u \le 1$.  Therefore the integral

[image: Mathematica graphics]

is equivalent to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The inner integral can be done symbolically and the outer numerically:

```
Integrate[Log[Log[1/v]] / (u Log[1/v]^(3/2)), {u, v, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> 0 < v < 1]
NIntegrate[%, {v, 0, 1}]
(*
  Log[-Log[v]] / Sqrt[-Log[v]]
  -3.48023
*)
```

Comment: Good job! I also know Mathematics stuff, but the point was more related to what Mathematica does.

Comment: @Chris'ssis I don't know much about improper multiple integrals.  Our textbook suggested that they were more difficult to deal with and that there wasn't a standard definition.  That might have something to do with *M*'s ability to deal with your integral.  I also tried `NLimit` on the integral with the domain `{x, 0 + a, 1 - a}, {y, 0 + a, 1 - a}`, as `a -> 0`.  With the option `Scale -> 1/10000`, the result close to the above.

Comment: I see.  I've read it. Thanks.

Comment: OK. I thank you for all details offered.

Answer (score 1):

With a little more patience :

```
f[x_, y_] = Log[Log[1/(x y)]] Log[1/(x y)]^(-0.5 - 1) ;
g[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, y], {y, 0, 1}]

NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
(* -3.48023 *)
```

without warnings/errors.